# how make ordring in this sqlite command?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have this sqllite query in android ..

```
 //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllMessages() 
    {
        return db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_FROMID,
                KEY_TOID,
                KEY_MESSAGE,
                DIR},
                null,
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }
```

i want to order desc the result according to KEY_ROWID 
how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a demo on using SQLite on Android and if you take a look at the [PicasaAlbumManager#getAlbumCursor](https://github.com/csaunders/Android-Tutorials/blob/master/sqlite/sqliteTutorial/src/ca/christophersaunders/tutorials/sqlite/db/PicasaAlbumManager.java) you can see how to set your OrderBy value.

In your case you would most likely do this:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_FROMID, KEY_TOID, KEY_MESSAGE, DIR};
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, projection, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID, null);
```

References:

- [Android Developer Documentation - SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Answer (score 0):

The query function has an orderBy String parameter, you pass exactly what you would to normally do a descending sort in a standard query, except that you omit ORDER BY.